# How do I solve this without using L'Hôpital's?

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How can I solve this problem without using L'Hôpital's rule?$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{(\sin(x)-x)(\cos(3x)-1)}{x(e^x -1)}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the taylor series of $sin(x)$ , $cos(3x)$ and $e^x$.

Comment: @Peter Inserting Taylor series and comparing leading terms is _exactly_ the same as using L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two basic limits
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\frac{1}{2},
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1
$$
so you can rewrite your limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}-9(\sin x-x)\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{(3x)^2}\frac{x}{e^x-1}
$$
and conclude the limit is …

Hints.

1. Use the fact that
   $$
   \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)g(x)=
   \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)
   $$
   provided both limits on the right hand side exist (which generalizes to a product of three or more factors).
2. What is $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x-x)$?

Comment: Beat me to it! $+1$

Comment: @KonKan “Not helpful enough→no vote”; “fails to communicate information→downvote”.

Comment: @egreg: thank you for the clarification. Now, I'm sure we are both busy enough to go on with this!  I'm happy you got my point ;)